# Series $\sum_{k=1}^\infty \left(\frac{1}{k}-\frac{1}{k+z} \right)$

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis

If $z$ is an integer, the sum of the series
  $$\sum_{k=1}^\infty \left(\frac{1}{k}-\frac{1}{k+z}\right)$$ is easy since it is a telescoping series. But if $z$ is a fraction, say $z=3/2$, I don't see why the series sums to $$\frac{8}{3}-\ln 4$$
Is there a formula for $z=m/n$, where $m,n$ are positive integers and $n\neq 1$?

Comment: This series is used to compute the [asymptotic expansion of harmonic numbers](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/467461/how-to-calculate-this-expression).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

For $\vert x \vert < 1$, if we define $f(x)$ as$$f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \left(x^n - x^{n+z}\right)$$ then $$\int_0^1 f(x) dx = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \left(\dfrac1n - \dfrac1{n+z}\right)$$
But we have $$f(x) = (1-x^z) \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} x^n = \dfrac{1-x^z}{1-x}$$
Hence,
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \left(\dfrac1n - \dfrac1{n+z}\right) = \int_0^1 \dfrac{1-x^z}{1-x}dx = I(z)$$
For $z=3/2$, we have
\begin{align}
I(3/2) & = \overbrace{\int_0^1 \dfrac{1-x^{3/2}}{1-x}dx = \int_0^1 \dfrac{1-t^3}{1-t^2} \cdot 2tdt}^{\text{Substitute }x = t^2} = \int_0^1 \dfrac{2t(1+t+t^2)}{1+t}dt\\
& = \int_0^1 \dfrac{2t((1+t)^2-t)}{1+t}dt = \int_0^1 2t(1+t) dt - 2 \int_0^1 \dfrac{t^2}{1+t} dt\\
& = \left(t^2 + \dfrac{2t^3}3\right)_{t=0}^{t=1} - 2 \int_0^1 \dfrac{t^2-1}{t+1}dt - 2 \int_0^1 \dfrac{dt}{1+t}\\
& = \dfrac53 - 2 \left(\dfrac{t^2}2 - t\right)_{t=0}^{t=1}-2\ln(2)\\
& = \dfrac53 - 2 \left(\dfrac12-1\right) - \ln(4) = \dfrac83 - \ln(4)
\end{align}

Answer (score 5):

To complete Marvis' (and now Mhenni's) answer let's notice that your series is, up to the Euler $\gamma$ constant ($0.577215\cdots$), the [digamma $\psi$ function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digamma_function#Recurrence_formula_and_characterization) i.e. 
$$\psi(z+1)+\gamma=\sum_{k=1}^\infty \left(\frac{1}{k}-\frac{1}{k+z}\right)$$

The formula for any fraction is well known too and named [Gauss's digamma theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digamma_function#Gauss.27s_digamma_theorem) :
$$\psi\left(\frac mk\right)=-\gamma-\ln(2k)-\frac{\pi}2\cot\left(\frac{m\pi}k\right)+2\sum_{n=1}^{\lfloor(k-1)/2\rfloor}\cos\left(\frac{2\pi nm}k\right)\ln\left(\sin\left(\frac{n\pi}k\right)\right)$$
This is valid for $\,0<m<k$. For other fractions (including negative non integer values) use repetitively $\;\displaystyle\psi(x+1)=\frac{1}{x}+\psi(x)$.

Concerning polygamma $\;\psi^{(n)}\left(\frac mk\right)\,$ for $n\in\mathbb{N}\ $ a formula was proposed by K. S. Kölbig in :
["The polygamma function and the derivatives of the cotangent function for rational arguments"](https://cds.cern.ch/record/298844).

Comment: Concerning the derivation of Gauss' theorem (and generalization!) see Kölbig's paper at CERN : ['The polygamma function and the derivatives of the cotangent function for rational arguments'](http://cds.cern.ch/record/298844)

Comment: The above formula is for $m<k$. If $m > k$, use the relation $\psi(x+1)=\frac{1}{x}+\psi(x)$.

Comment: @TCL; yes you are right I should have added that the second formula is for $0<\frac mk<1$ so that the numerator is in fact the remainder of the division of $j$ by $k$ for the fraction $\frac jk$ (if the remainder  is not $0$).

Comment: Isn't Gauss' formula a bit overkill for this problem?

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt: Well the OP wanted a formula for any fraction so possibly not. Anyway I like this formula and in fact (re)discovered it years earlier as well as the formula for $\;\psi^{(n)}\left(\frac mk\right)\;$ in terms of Clausen functions (found too earlier by Kurt Siegfried Kölbig). Excellent continuation,

Comment: Ah, yes, this is the way for any fraction. :-)

Answer (score 3):

Recalling the identity of the [$\psi$ function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digamma_function)

$$ \psi(z)=-\gamma+\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\left(\frac{1}{n+1}-\frac{1}{n+z}\right)\qquad z\neq0,-1,-2,-3,\ldots, $$

your series can be readily expressed in terms of the $\psi$ function

$$ \sum_{k=1}^\infty \left(\frac{1}{k}-\frac{1}{k+z}\right)= \psi(z+1)+\gamma. $$

Note that, for $z=\frac{m}{n},\, m,n\in \mathbb{N}$, you will not have a problem, since the singularities of the $\psi$ function are at $z=0,-1,-2,\dots.$

Answer (score 3):

Simple.

$$\begin{align}\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac1k-\frac1{k+\frac32}&=-2\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac1{2k+3}-\frac1{2k}\\&=\frac83-2\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac1{2k-1}-\frac1{2k}\\&=\frac83+2\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{k+1}}k\\&=\frac83-2\ln(2)\\&=\frac83-\ln(4)\end{align}$$

This approach works for any $z=\frac12+n,~n\in\Bbb N$.